# Why isn't Unity Burst's inspector showing some variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, unity-burst

While looking at the native code generated by Unity Burst to see whether it's leveraging SIMD, I have a hard time reading it as it is incompletely shown in the inspector.

For instance, there are variables that simply aren't shown, `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and `hv`.

I've modified the attributes so as to avoid any kind of optimization but still the same:

```
[BurstCompile(OptimizeFor = OptimizeFor.FastCompilation)]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
```

The Burst inspector:

[image]

The actual code:

```
[BurstCompile(OptimizeFor = OptimizeFor.FastCompilation)]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(FilterMethod))]
public static unsafe void VectorFullBandInner(
    in float* source, in float* target, in int length, in int stride, in int offset, ref Filter filter)
{
    ValidateArguments(source, target, length, stride, offset, ref filter);

    var h = filter.H;
    var z = filter.Z;
    var n = filter.HLength;
    var v = filter.VLength;

    for (var sample = 0; sample < length; sample += v)
    {
        var pos = Filter.UpdateZ(ref filter, source, sample);

        var sum = 0.0f;

        var tap = 0;

        int end;

        for (end = n - 4; tap < end; tap += 4)
        {
            var h0 = h[tap + 0];
            var h1 = h[tap + 1];
            var h2 = h[tap + 2];
            var h3 = h[tap + 3];

            var zP = pos - tap;

            var z0 = z[zP - 0];
            var z1 = z[zP - 1];
            var z2 = z[zP - 2];
            var z3 = z[zP - 3];

            var hv = new float4(h0, h1, h2, h3);
            var zh = new float4(z0, z1, z2, z3);

            sum += math.dot(hv, zh);
        }

        for (end = n - 1; tap < end; tap += 2)
        {
            var h0 = h[tap + 0];
            var h1 = h[tap + 1];

            var zP = pos - tap;

            var z0 = z[zP - 0];
            var z1 = z[zP - 1];

            var hv = new float2(h0, h1);
            var zv = new float2(z0, z1);

            sum += math.dot(hv, zv);
        }

        for (end = n - 0; tap < end; tap += 1)
        {
            var h0 = h[tap];

            var zP = pos - tap;

            var z0 = z[zP - 0];

            sum += math.dot(h0, z0);
        }

        target[sample] = sum;
    }
}
```

These variables are used and can't be optimized out but they're not shown.

Tried different options in UI, even for full debug information it's the same.

Am I missing something or is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
var h0 = h[tap + 0];
var h1 = h[tap + 1];
var h2 = h[tap + 2];
var h3 = h[tap + 3];
```

```
movsxd    rcx, ecx
```

Burst compiler optimizes struct operations [by packing and vectorizing them](https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/5c3052c9730b5a85a4c49fd33dfd535e?permalink_comment_id=4292176#gistcomment-4292176). `h0`-`h3` existing next to each other in memory can be reinterpreted as a single wider "struct" read/move operation. So `h1`,`h2`,`h3` declarations haven't disappeared but been collapsed to a single instruction in places of `h0`.